# how to keep focus on the parent control

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I have main user control that contain 3 controls, the problem is that when I click on any child control I lose the focus of the parent control  which has keydown behavior

any  idea how to keep the main control focused

Comment: Maybe this is useful:
[How to change a parent widgets background when a child widget has focus][1]

I´m researching about this too. 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071647/how-to-change-a-parent-widgets-background-when-a-child-widget-has-focus