# How to tell if child QWidget got focus

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, focus

With a complex layout, what would the easies way be to get a signal to a parent QWidget if a child has got focus?

One idea would be to somehow install event filters on all child QWidgets, but that seems somewhat silly.

Doesn't a parent QWidget really just somehow *know* that one of it's children has the focus?

EDIT:
Found this, maybe it's the only way then

[How to change a parent widget's background when a child widget has focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071647/how-to-change-a-parent-widgets-background-when-a-child-widget-has-focus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm lazy so this is what I did (cannot paste code since it's not on this machine).

Added a boolean to my widget base class, "listenToFocusChangesFromChildren"

Then I changed my base class focusInEvent to loop through all parents, and call "childGotFocus" on any that have that boolean set to true.

Lazy but seems to be very effective.

Answer (score 3):

You can install event filter for all necessary childs (is is OK), or override `QWidget::focusInEvent` for each child that needs to be monitored.

Comment: I proposed this method in my question. I was looking for something different, I don't want millions of event filters.